# Prove or disprove weak convergence for random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

> Suppose $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be independent random variables such that
>
> 1. $P(X_k=ke^k)=e^{-2k}, \ P(X_k=-ke^k)=e^{-2k}$,
> 2. $P(X_k=k)=\frac{1}{2}-e^{-2k},\ P(X_k=-k)=\frac{1}{2}-e^{-2k}$.
>
> Define $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n$. Can you find constants $a_n>0$ such that $a_nS_n$ converges to a non-degenerate distribution? Justify your answer.

I tried using the Lyapunov condition but it was of no avail. Seeing the increasing spread of the random variables I get the feeling that the answer is negative but I am not sure. Any hints on how to solve this one?

Comment: I find the variance $Var(X_k)=k^2(3-2e^{-2k}) \to +\infty$ as $k\to+\infty$. Do you agree?

Comment: I do. I checked this while trying the Lyapunov condition with a certain $(2+\delta) $^{th} moment. Which direction are you specifically hinting at?

Comment: Because probabilities in $1$ are summable, eventually $S_n$ will only contain terms of type $2$ with probabilities $1/2$ which should simplify your calculations. If anything, $a_n=n^{-3/2}$ based on growth of variance.

Comment: @thenumber17 I was also trying to calculate the sum $s_n$ in Lyapunov but I did not manage to reach something. Characteristic function $E[e^{itX_k}]=2e^{-2k}(\cos(tke^k)-\cos(tk))+\cos(tk)$ did not give anything either (for $k\to +\infty$).

Comment: @A.S. - Do you think there is a neat way of putting it? Suppose I try constants of the order $n^{-\frac{3}{2}}$, how do I check whether they work or not?

Comment: @JimmyR. - I tried characteristic functions myself, yielded nothing. Do you think the answer is affirmative at all?

Comment: @thenumber17 I do not know yet. Another idea that does not work: If we consider $Y_k=\frac1kX_k$ with $Var(Y_k)=\frac{1}{k^2}Var(X_k)=3-e^{-2k}$ but then $a_n$ would be the $n-th$ harmonic number and this would again diverge (??).

Comment: $s_n$ from Lyapunov's is on the order of $n^{3/2}$, so the condition is satisfied and you have convergence to a normal.

Comment: Define $Y_k=k$ if $X_k>0$ and $Y_k=-k$ if $X_k<0$, and $T_n=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$. Then $X_n=Y_n$ except for a finite number of indexes $n$ hence $S_n-T_n$ is almost surely bounded. Now you are probably able to show that $T_n/n^{3/2}$ converges in distribution to a centered normal distribution, for example using characteristic functions. Hence the same convergence holds for $S_n/n^{3/2}$.

Comment: Lyapunov's tells you that for independent $X_k=k^{\alpha}B$ where $B$ is symmetric Bernoulli on $-1,1$, $S_n/s_n$ converges to $N(0,1)$ for ALL $\alpha\in R$.